# iiyama X2483HSU factory reset

Tags: display, factory-defaults

So on the OSD I've changed the input from auto to manual and to HDMI, but the problem is I don't have the HDMI cable. So now my monitor (iiyama ProLite X2483HSU) constantly displays "No signal detected!" and I can't get into On Screen Display to change input back to auto. Is there a key combination or something that can reset it back to the factory settings?

Comment: At the lower right hand edge of the screen can you find the menu button? What happens when you press it? There is a factory reset option in the menus, but if we can get you access to the menu changing the input should be enough.

Comment: It turns out that the "AUTO" button pressed for 3 seconds brings up input selection window. Problem solved.

Comment: Have the same problem, but this will not work. My monitor is XB2783HSU.

Answer (score 17):

#### tl;dr;

Press the *AUTO* button for 2 seconds. Then select the input of your choice.

#### monitor reference

*iiyama 24" LED ProLite XB2483HSU-B1 - 1920 x 1080 pixels - 4 ms - Format large 16/9 - Dalle AMVA+ - Pivot - HDMI - haut-parleurs - Noir*

#### what I understand so far

From the moment I connect an HDMI input, the automatically selected input will always be HDMI. So if I plug a VGA input I got the "No signal detected!" message.

By pressing the *AUTO* button for 2 seconds, you can go back to manual input selection and choose VGA (D-sub) again.

See John Tetmaier answers.

Comment: Which idiot decided to add an often-used function to a button and not print it on the plastic!?

Comment: I honestly thought my screen (B2483HSU) was defective (didn't auto-detect the signal via DP, couldn't enter menu via `Enter` button), but this did the trick. Confusing functionality and design decitions right there, but thanks to your advice all is good now.

Comment: This also works for the `ProLite E2483HS`

Comment: You're a star; thanks for that. What a shonky piece of design… :-(

Comment: Thank you @Raphaël this answer saved me a lot of trouble!  Not being able to bring up the onscreen display when not connected seems a little odd to me, but I guess they had their reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In the same situation, I've press the "Auto" button for 6 or 8 sg untill came on screen a little orange menu where you choose the entry method. My screen : iiyama ProLite B2712HDS.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (switch the wrong input) but I solved it !

Computer on, screen plugged on it.
No light on your screen (no blue or orange one) :

1) select **UP and DOWN** in the same time, as long as you can, and press once the power button **ON**. [Up and down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG41U.jpg)

2) Ok, "NO signal..." and the light is blue *- still pressing UP and DOWN*

3) And be careful! The light becomes orange and there, you have to select right now **DOWN and 2** [Down and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92G8g.jpg)

-> And there the light becomes again blue with the menu!!! You can take off your fingers, but beware you have 3 seconds to change your input.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. I always got 'no-signal'. The only way to get the menu open seems to be when you have input-signal.

My solution:

I tried different cables like DVI, VGA, HDMI and the VGA worked for me, i got signal and i was able to change the input settings to auto.